# Unity C# problems in finding classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

I want to build the entire tree of classes in unity
To do so, I created a script that prints all possibile subclasses of a class in input and attached it on an empty object, but it returned nothing

```
public class FindAll : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void FindAllDerivedTypes(Assembly assembly, Type baseType)
    {
        TypeInfo typeInfo = baseType.GetTypeInfo();
        List<string> classNames = new List<string>();
        foreach(Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if(baseType.IsSubclassOf(t))
            {
                Debug.Log(t.Name + " Subclass of " + baseType.Name);
                FindAllDerivedTypes(assembly, t);
            }
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        FindAllDerivedTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(UnityEngine.Object));
    }
```

But nothing is written in the console in unity
What I didn't understand properly?

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate since it is extremely similar. The magic you are looking for is happening in `WholeEditorAddPopup.OpenPopup` when initializing `window.m_AvailableTypes = ...`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're conditional is backwards? With this code:

```
if (baseType.IsSubclassOf(t))
```

... you're checking if the BASE class is a sub class of any classes found in the executing assembly. I think you want it to read:

```
if (t.IsSubclassOf(baseType))
```

This is assuming you're looking for your own custom classes that are derived from Unity's Object class.